# Error while Importing 4m Snowflake 2 Power BI-converting invalid input with source encoding UTF-8 using ICU. Rejected bytes began with: 9273

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am able to connect to Snowflake and import data from other tables but when I import a particular table then get this error message.

VW_STOCK_AND_SALES
Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Snowflake][Support] (50311) Error converting invalid input with source encoding UTF-8 using ICU. Rejected bytes began with: 9273..
 '.

Help pls.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid UTF-8 characters were detected. The default ENCODING file format option when creating a named file format in Snowflake is UTF-8.

Have you tried to use a [named file format](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#create-file-format) that has the correct ENCODING file format option set for the string input data?

Comment: Hi, My File format is CSV and While loading data I was getting error and upon search I found adding VALIDATE_UTF8=false to load will ignore the error. Now when I try to connect using power BI I am getting again this error message. Is there any way I can fix this in Select Query like using CONVERT.